# Videos that show Gazebo doing hard dynamics?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Are there any videos that show Gazebo doing any moderately hard robot dynamics problems?  Running? Hopping? Jumping?  Catching?  Sliding?  The most "dynamic" examples I can find just show mostly-kinematic situations, such as slow walking with a bit of ZMP to keep the effective CG over the feet.  The DRC videos show the Atlas robot doing a lot less than the videos of the real Atlas robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3563/videos-that-show-gazebo-doing-hard-dynamics?/) by [John Nagle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/395/john-nagle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-07-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John Nagle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/395/john-nagle/) on 2013-07-16**:
What I'm looking for here are results comparable to what OpenHRP3 was delivering a few years ago. OpenHRP3 has its own physics engines, developed at universities in Japan specifically for accurate robot simulation of humanoid robots. OpenHRP3 looks quite effective, but the support resources are mostly in Japanese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have not seen examples that you are looking for. The capabilities exist in Gazebo, someone just has to do the work to make ATLAS or some other robot jump or hop.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0